# How to change the Messaging and keyboard apps to stock ones on LG Optimus Net P690 running Cyanogenmod7?

Tags: cyanogenmod

Is it in any way possible to replace CM7's boring messaging interface with the stock messaging app from the LG stock roms (the one with chat bubbles), also, where would I be able to get a keyboard similar/exactly the same to the stock LG keyboard on the Optimus Net?

This is what the stock keyboard looks like (I couldn't find a picture in portrait mode, sorry): [image: Stock Keyboard Image].

I found a ported stock LG keyboard, but as you can see in Cyano, there is a useless smilie button and every single button is bigger than what they're supposed to be from the LG keyboard.

Could someone help me/direct me to how I might be able to replace the messaging app and keyboard from CM7 with the apps I'm looking for? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Download the apk files of the stock keyboard and messaging apps and copy them to the current directory. You can also copy them from /system/app/ directory in the system.img file(use magiciso to mount it) present in the stock firmware file(usually .tar) Start an adb session and execute the following lines:

Mounting system partition as read-write:

```
$ adb shell mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock03 /system
```

Removing CM's apps(change the names):

```
$ adb shell rm /system/app/CM_messaging_app.apk
$ adb shell rm /system/app/CM_keyboard_app.apk
```

Installing stock apps(change the names):

```
$ adb install stock_messaging_app.apk
$ adb install stock_keyboard_app.apk
```

I would recommend 'hacker's keyboard'( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard&hl=en) over the stock keyboard apps though.

Comment: I've tried your method with installing multiple versions of the stock Gingerbread Mms.apk, though for the Mms apps I found, it always fails to install. What could be causing this?

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Comment: When I try to install the apk manually (for testing purposes if it would work before mounting to the system) I get application not installed messages. I then tried mounting it to the system/app/ folder via the terminal then my messaging app just vanished altogether.